# What could cause a long running transaction with trx_query null in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Query:

```
SELECT
  trx_id,
  trx_state,
  timestampdiff(
      SECOND,
      trx_started,
      now()
  ) duration,
  trx_query
FROM information_schema.INNODB_TRX;
```

Result:

```
trx_id          trx_state   duration    trx_query
329182111765896 RUNNING     25043   
7511439990      RUNNING     26  
7511442157      LOCK WAIT   22          select * from...
7511442102      LOCK WAIT   22          update `xxx` set ...
329182111487256 RUNNING     0           select * from ...
```

I noticed a very interesting transaction:

```
 329182111765896    RUNNING     25043
```

It's a very long running transaction with trx_query null. How could it happen? What is the possible cause for that transaction?

Comment: did you find the cause?

Comment: Run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` a the same time.  Maybe there is a clue there -- such as with some query with a _similar_ "Time".

Comment: i bet you're using sqlalchemy or other ORM likes